# How can I access main activity to get latitude and longitude in order to change url, and how can I change the url's languages automatically,

Tags: java, android

I am doing a toilet android app which get the closest toilet, but I face problems.
I want to get `mainactivity`'s latitude and longitude variable in order to change the url's latitude and longitude information which is in `main2activty`. How can I pass the value between different activity?
Thank you for your help. Below is my, `mainactivity` and `main2activity` java code.

This is my `mainactivty`

```
package hk.android.1;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG1 = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button button3;
    private Button button4;
    private Button button5;
    private Button button6;
    public static double latitude;
    public static double longitube;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    protected Location mLastLocation;

    private String mLatitudeLabel;
    private String mLongitudeLabel;
    private TextView mLatitudeText;
    private TextView mLongitudeText;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button_3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMain2Activity();
            }
        });

        button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMain3Activity();
            }
        });

        button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMain4Activity();
            }
        });

        button6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMain5Activity();
            }
        });

        mLatitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.latitude_label);
        mLongitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.longitude_label);
        mLatitudeText = findViewById((R.id.latitude_text));
        mLongitudeText = findViewById((R.id.longitude_text));

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    }

    public void openMain2Activity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openMain3Activity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void openMain4Activity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main4Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void openMain5Activity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main5Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        } else {
            getLastLocation();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    public void getLastLocation() {
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                            mLastLocation = task.getResult();

                            mLatitudeText.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %f",
                                    mLatitudeLabel,
                                    mLastLocation.getLatitude()));

                            latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                            String lat = Double.toString(latitude);
                            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                            textView.setText(lat);

                            mLongitudeText.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %f",
                                    mLongitudeLabel,
                                    mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

                            longitube = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                            String longt = Double.toString(longitube);
                            TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                            textView2.setText(longt);

                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG1, "getLastLocation:exception", task.getException());
                            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.no_location_detected));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void showSnackbar(final String text) {
        View container = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_container);
        if (container != null) {
            Snackbar.make(container, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void showSnackbar(final int mainTextStringId, final int actionStringId,
                              View.OnClickListener listener) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                getString(mainTextStringId),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(getString(actionStringId), listener).show();
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void startLocationPermissionRequest() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG1, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");

            showSnackbar(R.string.permission_rationale, android.R.string.ok,
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            startLocationPermissionRequest();
                        }
                    });

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG1, "Requesting permission");
            startLocationPermissionRequest();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG1, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                Log.i(TAG1, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                getLastLocation();
            } else {
                showSnackbar(R.string.permission_denied_explanation, R.string.settings,
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `main2activty`.

```
package hk.android.1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Main2Activity";
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 1000;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
        clearScreen();
    }

    private static void clearScreen() {
        for (int i = 0; i < PAGE_SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh()
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");
                myUpdateOperation();
            }
        });

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_red_light,
                android.R.color.holo_blue_light,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_purple);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();

    }

    public void loadRecyclerViewData(){
    double latitude = MainActivity.latitude;
    double longitube = MainActivity.longitube;
    String language = getResources().getString(R.string.lang);
    //String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    private String URL_DATA = "http://xxxx/toilet/json-toilet.php?lat=" + latitude + "&lng=" + longitube + "&lang=" + language;
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_DATA,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                            for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                ListItem item;
                                item = new ListItem(
                                        o.getString("name"),
                                        o.getString("address"),
                                        o.getString("distance")
                                );
                                listItems.add(item);
                            }
                            adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }      catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), volleyError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    public void openMainActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void myUpdateOperation()
    {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                  {
                                      @Override
                                      public void run()
                                      {
                                          mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                          openMainActivity();
                                      }
                                  }, 2555
        );
    }
}
```

I expect that I can get the closest toilet after get the latitude and longitude information to `main2activity` and update the URL_DATA.

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow. I would suggest updating the naming of your activities, and buttons. You are now using names such as Main2Activity, Main3Activity, button2, and button3. It is much easier to use descriptive names such as MapsActivity, DetailsActivity depending on the functionality. This makes your code much easier to read for you and others.

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome. If you find an answer helpful you can upvote it, or mark it as the answer. You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can add extras to your intent to pass data to your new activity.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
 intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
 intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
 startActivity(intent);
```

In your `Main2Activity` you can read out these values by using:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
double latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0.0);
double latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0);
```

0.0 is the default value that gets used when you didn't sent along the double value. 
You can read more about intents in the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)